# Pass MATLAB vector to C++ Eigen using MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, mex

I am attempting to pass a MATLAB vector to Eigen in C++, using a MEX class as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "mex.hpp"
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <Eigen/Dense>


using namespace matlab::data;
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using matlab::mex::ArgumentList;
ArrayFactory factory;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
    void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
        
    VectorXd m;
    m = Map<VectorXd>(inputs[0]);

}
};
```

The offense seems to be that there is no conversion from a MATLAB TypedArray to a Vectorxd from Eigen. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: To construct a `Map<VectorXd>` you need to pass a `double` pointer and the size of the vector -- if you need this a lot, write yourself some helper functions.

Comment: @chtz I've been trying the following, but it also does not seem to be working:
`Matrix<double, 2, 1> m = Map< Matrix<double, 2, 1> > (inputs[3]);`

Comment: @ I also tried `Matrix<double, 2, 1> m = Map< Matrix<double, 2, 1> > (inputs[3],2,1)` and got the following message:
`no known
conversion from 'matlab::data::Array' to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, 0,
Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >::PointerArgType' (aka 'double *')` . Does this mean there's no way to convert a TypedArray to a Eigen Vector/Matrix?

Comment: Can't help you much with the mex-part of your problem -- you need to somehow extract a data pointer from your `matlab::data::Array` -- there is likely a member function for that.

Comment: @chtz thank you! that worked. Just like you said, using `m1.release().get()` gets my a pointer to my `matlab::data::Array` and now I can construct a VectorXd. Thanks again!